# PHP - Tree of Array References, first append to a new array is lost

Tags: php, arrays, tree, reference

I have a tree structure composed of nested associative arrays. I have a set of paths that I want to add to the tree, where each element in the path is the name of a node. The code below should create the node "2" under "a" (which it does) and create the nodes "i", "ii" and "iii" under "2". For some reason though, the first node created under "2" gets lost. It will print that it's being created, but `print_r` only shows "ii" and "iii".

```
$tree = array(
    name => 'root',
    children => array(
        array(
            name => 'a',
            children => array( ),
        ),
    ),
);


$paths = array(
    array('a','2','i'),
    array('a','2','ii'),
    array('a','2','iii'),
);


foreach ($paths as $path) {
    $node =& $tree;
    $found = true;
    while($found && count($path) > 0) {
        $name = $path[0];
        $found = false;
        echo "looking for $name\n";
        foreach ($node['children'] as &$child) {
            if($name == $child['name']) {
                echo "found $name\n";
                $node =& $child;
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($found) {
            array_shift($path);
        }
    }
    if(!$found) {
        echo "didn't find $name\n";
        while(count($path) > 0) {
            $name = array_shift($path);
            echo "creating $name in ".$node['name']."\n";
            $newNode = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'children' => array(),
            );
            $node['children'][] = $newNode;
            $node =& $newNode;
        }
    }
}

print_r($tree);
```

I suspect the problem has to do with how I'm initializing the children of "2", since it will be created inside the loop, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: So I figured out how to make it work... Changing that last inner loop from:

```
        $newNode = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'children' => array(),
        );
        $node['children'][] = $newNode;
        $node =& $newNode;
```

to

```
        $children =& $node['children'];
        $children[] = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'children' => array()
        );
        $node =& $children[count($children)-1];
```

seems to do it, but I'm not sure why. A good explanation is due.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those references are hurting my brain, however there is one obvious error I can see in:

```
$node['children'][] = $newNode;
$node =& $newNode;
```

The second line overwrites `$node` with a reference to `$newNode`, so the first line is unused.

In your new version, you're creating the `$children` array, making the manipulation and then setting the `$node` reference, which is why it works.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? $node should be a reference to the parent node, so I'm trying to append $newNode to it, then move down to to the new node for the next iteration. What do you mean when you say the "first line is unused?" Appending a child doesn't do anything?